# How to add a colorbar to a plt.bar chart?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, math

I am trying to create a self updating chart that displays a horizontal line and color bars based on a y-axis value of interest. So bars might be colored red if they are definitely above this value (given a 95% confidence interval), blue if they are definitely below this value, or white if they contain this value. something similar to this:

[image: plot with colorbar]

The problem I have is I cant display the colorbar on my plot. I managed to color each bar based on a LinearSegmentedColormap and some conditions, but I cant manage to display this colorbar on my image.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt
import matplotlib.axes
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])

means = []
for i in df.index:
    means.append(df.loc[i].mean())
    
std = []
for i in df.index:
    std.append(df.loc[i].std())

# compute the 95% confidence intervals
conf = []
for i in range(len(means)):
    margin = (1.96*std[i])/sqrt(len(df.columns))
    conf.append(margin)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1)
bars = plt.bar(df.index, means, yerr= conf, tick_label = df.index, capsize = 10)

#Setup the plot
yinterest = 43000
plt.gca().spines.get('top').set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines.get('right').set_visible(False)
plt.axhline(yinterest, color  = 'black', label = '4300')

#setting the y-interest tick
plt.draw()
labels = [w.get_text() for w in ax.get_yticklabels()]
locs=list(ax.get_yticks())
labels+=[str(yinterest)]
locs+=[float(yinterest)]
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.set_yticks(locs)
plt.draw()

#setting up the colormap
colormap = cm.get_cmap('RdBu', 10)
colores = []
for i in range(len(means)):
    color = (yinterest-(means[i]-conf[i]))/((means[i]+conf[i])-(means[i]-conf[i]))
    bars[i].set_color(colormap(color))
```

I am fairly new to python (or programming for that matter) and I have searched everywhere for a solution but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

The first hint is to use *pandasonic* methods to compute plot data
(much more concise):

```
means = df.mean(axis=1)
std = df.std(axis=1)
conf = (std * 1.96 / sqrt(df.shape[1]))
```

And to draw your plot, run:

```
yinterest = 39541
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax.spines.get('top').set_visible(False)
ax.spines.get('right').set_visible(False)
colors = (yinterest - (means - conf)) / (2 * conf)
colormap = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdBu', 10)
plt.bar(df.index, means, yerr=conf, tick_label=df.index, capsize=10, color=colormap(colors))
cbar = plt.colorbar(plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=colormap), orientation='horizontal')
cbar.set_label('Color', labelpad=5)
plt.axhline(yinterest, color='black', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

One trick that allows to avoid colouring the bars after their
generation is that I compute *colors*, which are then converted to
a color map and passed to *plt.bar*.

To draw the color bar, use *plt.colorbar*.

I changed the value of *yinterest* to that included in your picture and got
something similar to your picture, but with a color bar:

[image]